# Validating image on a webpage using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to write a code to visit on each product on a product listing page and extract information. Can anyone suggest me the logic and code so that I can move ahead in my project?

Code when image is available:

```
<img class="btn zoom" src="http://asset1.marksandspencer.com/is/image/mands/RC_01_T62_9451K_H4_X_EC_90?$PDP_PROD_IMAGE$" data-image-set-count="3" data-caro-slide-rel="1">
```

Code when images is not available:

```
<img class="btn zoom" src="http://asset1.marksandspencer.com/is/image/?$PDP_PROD_IMAGE$" data-image-set-count="1" data-caro-slide-rel="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on your query but you if you want to find the List of Images present , Images Loaded vs not Loaded .

All Images can be captured in the Section using driver.findElements ( By.tag using "img". This will return the List of all section if image in specific section. Good not  to try on complete page or on driver as you may find more image link tag.

So first identify the section t test , then get the WebElement of the section from the driver . Then use the above way to find ALL image List

Now to find the Loaded and not loaded list :

When Image NOT Loaded your source ( src) contains

is/image/?$PDP_PROD_IMAGE$"

When Image available and loaded your  source ( src)contains

is/image/mands/RC_01_T62_9451K_H..........

So write a xpath or css Regular expression which can list you the loaded and not loaded image by comparing your src parameter

**Equals** to "src="http://asset1.marksandspencer.com/is/image/mands/RC_01_T62_9451K_H4_X_EC_90?$PDP_PROD_IMAGE$""  => Not Loaded Image

**Not** equals to src="http://asset1.marksandspencer.com/is/image/mands/RC_01_T62_9451K_H4_X_EC_90?$PDP_PROD_IMAGE$""  => Loaded Image